# HHVM compatibility with the Silex framework

Tags: silex, hhvm

I can see that [HHVM can already run](http://hhvm.com/frameworks/) some well known PHP frameworks.

I was wondering if anyone tried to run Silex with HHVM, hands on experience?

Are they compatible?

I'm asking since I can see that currently Symphony passes 98% of unit-tests on HHHVM and I would like to get my hands dirty with these two technologies.

Comment: The best way to find out is to try yourself. HHVM is trivial to set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does seem to be possible, see [this](http://blog.bitexpert.de/blog/silex-running-on-hhvm/) tutorial from Stephan Hochdörfer.

You can also upload your project's composer.json [here](http://hhvm.h4cc.de/) to see if any extra dependencies you have are currently being tested against HHVM on Travis CI.

Comment: Can you mark the above as an answer if it answered your question? Thanks!